# Java Regular Expression Matches

Tags: java, regex

I have a method to check my users input in a comment text field.

```
public boolean isValidComment(String commentString) {
  String expression = "[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+";
  CharSequence inputStr = commentString;
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
  return matcher.matches();
}
```

This works for me, but I need to change my pattern.  The user should be able to type any character with the exception of these characters: `<> {} []`.

How do I set up the pattern to allow everything except those above?

Comment: You should have googled this!

Comment: You might be better off allowing the user to type whatever they wish in the comment text field, and then making sure your code escapes the user text safely before placing it into a database or onto a webpage. For instance, escaping < with &lt; makes it safe for display on a webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[^\<\>\{\}\[\]]+
```

In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of `Pattern` for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN = 
                                     Pattern.compile("^[^\\<\\>\\{\\}\\[\\]]+$");
```

And use the constant:

```
return MY_PATTERN.matcher(commentString).matches();
```

Answer (score 4):

`[^characters to disallow]`.

The `^` negates the character class, matching anything except what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it but the format is :
String expression = `"[^\\\<\\\>\\\{\\\}\\\[\\\]]+"`
the ^ symbol is for all characters but the following ones.